# Multi module Maven project with Spring - Do I include Spring in the Web layer or Service layer?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

So I have a multi-module Maven project that simply has two child modules: Web, and Service. The Web layer has only one controller and one method in that controller that simply displays the age of a dog on the screen.

Where does the dog come from? Well I have another module that is a 'service' layer that basically contains a Dog store/service, and this dog store actually only contains one Dog object at any given time (this is all for learning purposes).

I need to use Spring's Dependency Injection functionality in my Service module in order to autowire a Dog object into my Dog store, and I obviously need Spring's D.I. functionality in my Web module, in order to autowire a Dog store/service into my Dog controller, but I don't know WHICH POM.xml should contain a Spring dependency.

***My question is this***: Do I need to put a Spring dependency in both the service module AND the web module? The end project is going to be built from the web module, in fact. The web module will have a dependency for the service module (because I need that Dog Service and Dog object classes).

If I don't include spring as a dependency in my Service-module, then the compiler will freak out when I use an annotation like @Autowire. So this leaves my a bit confused. Which module do I put the spring dependency in?

Perhaps just put the entire Spring Web MVC dependency in the Service module, and let the Web module 'inherit' all the custom service classes, PLUS the downloaded Spring jars? (Since, again, the web-module will have a dependency on the service module). This just seems a little counter-intuitive to me because it's not really the service-module that is dependent on Spring Web MVC. Really, the service module only needs Spring Context. But the confusion here is that the "FINAL" spring context (Dispatcher Servlet, etc) will only be used once, from the Web-module build.

I'm ONLY creating the service-module so that my web-module can inherit those classes I've built, but should the web-module inherit the spring classes from the service-module, or should the web-module actually declare the spring classes in it's own POM.xml? If it is the latter option, then won't the service-module freak out when it sees that I'm using annotations and other things from Spring framework, without having a dependency to it?

I realize that was a lot, but I was trying to be as clear as possible in my situation, and I hope that my question makes sense. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a parent POM to your application and keep all dependencies defined there and make your web and service modules are child modules. See [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) for more details

In your parent POM, dependencies are defined something like this,

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Use above defined dependency in your web and service modules,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, add service module as a dependency to your web module.